# edit/delete image after uploading it in the register page

Tags: php

i have uploaded a image , i want to delete the uploaded image and upload new one in the edit page . how to do this with php code

the code to upload image :

Upload image

iwant to delete ie update image for registered user by deleting old one and replacing new one

Comment: I guess, you have stored the name of image uploaded into your server in the database . You can simply use unlink() and upload a new one

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to delete the file and overwrite it with a new one. then you just delete them with unlink first.

```
if(file_exists("<file_path>")) unlink("<file_path>")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update image in the database use update query 
         mysql_query("update tablename set imagefield='$_FILES['image']['name']' where id='1'");
use it to delete image from folder

unlink('../upload/'.$imagename);